# Creating dynamic key/value object in C#

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C# and trying to grasp concepts on object, list and dictionary. I have a method which returns data from a RTD server.

```
private object getBalance(RtdClient client)
{

  int count = 5;
  var types = new[] {
    "date",
    "amount",
    "balance"
  };

  String[] balance = new String[count];
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    var name = types[i];
    var value = Client.getDetails(client, types[i], dateValue.Text);
    balance[i] = value.ToString();
  }

  return balance;
}
```

It returns data as:

```
balance{string[3]}  string[]
```

**What I would like to do is get data as following:**

```
  "date": "17 July"
  "amount": "234"
```

So I can do `balance.date` or `balance.amount`.

Currently on `displayData` method, I cast as:

```
string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)balance).Cast<object>()
                             .Select(x => x.ToString())
                             .ToArray();

var outputFields = new[] {
    "dateValue",
    "amountValue",
    "balanceValue"
};

for (var i = 0; i < outputFields.Length; i++)
{
  outputFields[i].Text = quotes[i];
}
```

I am trying to avoid having to maintain two different arrays (outputFields and types).

How can I get data as key value pairs which can be looped?

Comment: Show your Client class along with your Client.getDetails() method

Comment: @ChandanKumar Client just returns a double number.